# Charts.js (2.9.4) Gridlines not displaying under Line Graph

Tags: chart.js, linechart

Does anyone know if this is a bug in charts.js 2.X ? Under the line graph it won't display the gridlines. I have tested this in Charts.js 3.X and it works perfectly but I need to use 2.X for IE11 support... I have tried many things with no luck, I would assume this option would be a gridLines option, but seems like it might be a bug.

```js
options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,   
    elements: {
      line: {
        tension: 0
      }
    },    
    layout: {
      padding: 16
    },

    legend: {
      display: false
    },

    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        display: false
      }
    },

    scales: {  
      xAxes: [{
        id: 'x',
        display: true,
        ticks: {
          display: true,
          beginAtZero: false,
          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
          fontColor: '#000',
          fontStyle: 'bold',
          fontSize: 12
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Year',
          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
          fontColor: '#000',
          fontStyle: 'bold',
          fontSize: 12,
          lineHeight: 0,
          padding: {top: 15, right: 0, bottom: 5, left: 0 }
        },
        gridLines: { 
          display: true,
          drawOnChartArea: true
        }
      }],

      yAxes: [{
        id: 'y',
        display: true,
        ticks: {
          display: true,
          beginAtZero: false,
          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
          fontColor: '#000',
          fontStyle: 'normal',
          fontSize: 12,
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Speed (MB/s)',
          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
          fontColor: '#000',
          fontStyle: 'bold',
          fontSize: 12,
          lineHeight: 0,
          padding: {top: 10, right: 0, bottom: 10, left: 0 }
        },
        gridLines: { 
          display: true,
          drawOnChartArea: true
        }
      }]
    }
}
```

[Line graph no gridlines under line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXUoH.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you set `backgroundColor` to white in your dataset, by default in v2 the fill is true and takes the backgroundcolor, in v3 by default the line doesnt get filled so you need to either provide a semi tranparant white backgroundColor or set fill to false as shown below

Example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Points',
      data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
      borderWidth: 3,
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      borderColor: 'blue',
      fill: false
    }]
  },
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Okay this makes sense, thank you LeeLenalee